# Swiper ES module web.config for IE11 support

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, swiper.js

I am using swiper in a react app. In Internet Explorer 11 it pop up syntax error 
(about arrow function since it is not supported by IE11)
I added the code suggested by the github repository but it doesn't work still getting syntax error on dom modular. Which use function arrow instead of been transformed into ES5. Anyone can help me correct this issue?

Syntax Error:
Object.key(Methods).forEach((methodName) => { **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_mod7_dist_dom7_modular**...});

.babelrc:

```
{
"presets": [
"es2015",
"react"
]
}
```

webpack file part:

```
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|node_modules\/(?!(dom7|ssr-window|swiper)\/).*)/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: ['env'],
      },
    },
  },
```

package json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@firebase/firestore": "^0.1.4",
    "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^0.9.6",
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^0.14.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.6.1",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.5",
    "cssnano": "^3.7.1",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.5.4",
    "es6-promise": "^3.2.1",
    "firebase": "^4.6.2",
    "firebase-admin": "5.4.1",
    "firebase-functions": "0.7.1",
    "firebase-tools": "^3.15.1",
    "firebaseui": "2.3.0",
    "glob": "^7.0.5",
    "hashbuster": "^1.0.1",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.1.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.0",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "node-geopoint": "^1.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "normalize.css": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss": "^5.0.21",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss-load-config": "1.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "1.2.1",
    "postcss-pxtorem": "^3.3.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "pubsub-js": "^1.5.3",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-avatar-editor": "^10.3.0",
    "react-css-modules": "^4.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-geosuggest": "^2.6.0",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.2",
    "react-modal": "^3.1.6",
    "react-onclickoutside": "^5.11.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.7",
    "react-router-sitemap": "^1.1.3",
    "react-scrollchor": "^4.0.0",
    "react-svg-inline": "^2.0.0",
    "react-times": "^2.2.8",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "slug": "^0.9.1",
    "swiper": "^4.1.6"
  },
```

Comment: Can you post your .babelrc file?

Comment: Either your `exclude` part is wrong (I'm not super familiar with how webpack uses it), or your babelrc isn't set up to do the transforms you want

Comment: I added babelrc file

Comment: I'm not sure if it's needed, but in order to get env to work properly for my project, I had to have a .babelrc like this: https://github.com/AnilRedshift/chrome-extension-webpack-boilerplate/blob/master/.babelrc

Does that fix it for you?

Comment: or maybe the issue is your webpack.config.js with options: {
        presets: ['env'],
      },